# Не переопределяется стиль CSS. Приоритет стилей

Tags: css, bootstrap

Есть страничка. К ней подключен bootstrap.

```css
/* CSS должен применяться после bootstrap.min.css,
   но StackOverflow этого не позволяет */
label {
    font-weight: 100;
}

.search-from-group .input-group { 
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

input {
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container search-from-group">
   <div class="row text-center">
    <form action="" method="get">
        <p class="text-center"><label for="link-to-group-field">1212sdfле:</label></p>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input placeholder="https://vk.com/licey_pri_ulgtu" class="form-control" id="link-to-group-field" name="link-to-group" type="text">
        </div>
    </form>
   </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Обратите внимание на style `input`'а. Только написав напрямую, в теге, `border-radius: 10px` получается изменить радиус закругления. Но если вынести стиль в отдельный файл и убрать style в теге, то стиль не применяется.

```
input {
    border-radius: 50px !imortant;
}
#link-to-group-field {
    border-radius: 50px !imortant;
}
```

Ни одна из этих конструкций не хочет работать. Вопросов несколько: почему? **Как узнать приоритеты, который расставил браузер?** Почему не работает !important?

Comment: А если вообще не писать ни important, ни imortant?

Comment: Без important не работает..

Comment: Блин, я хотел написать ответ про веса селекторов, но не смог найти внятного объяснения в стандарте CSS3, напишите кто-нибудь за меня)

Answer (score 2):

Такого понятия нет в `CSS` -  `!imortant`, наверно вы хотели написать `!important`. 

Для переопределения стилей вы просто конкретно укажите индетификатор `input`

```
#link-to-group-field{
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Походу пора спать.. Спасибо. Но все же, можно ли как-то понять, как расставил приоритеты браузер? А то получится, что бутстраповский класс скажет !important, позже я захочу переопределить и тд и тп. Можно ли как-то это отследить?

Comment: Если хотите перекрыть стили написанных именно в элементе можете использовать !important, но запомните, многие IE игнорируют данное значение, а для браузера  важен порядок описания стилей,  кто позже, тот и приоритетней.

Comment: @IvanBlohin без примера сказать про приоритеты трудно (и по-хорошему !important использовать не стоит вообще никогда)

Comment: Файл моих стилей идет после бутсраповского. style из тега я убираю. Почему не становится приоритетнее мой стиль?

Comment: @IvanBlohin  Значит вы что то не то сделали )) если есть ссылка, покажите посмотрим, если в первом файле стили установленны уже с !important, далее вы наверно не сможете преопределить стили

Comment: @IvanBlohin давайте пример (в идеале сниппетом в самом вопросе, но можно хотя бы ссылку)

Comment: @Arsen https://ideone.com/zTZz8B

Comment: @IvanBlohin это нерабочий пример и бутстрап к нему не подключен, дайте полностью самодостаточный и рабочий пример, чтобы мы тут не гадали

Comment: А вообще у простого селектора `input` слишком низкий приоритет и вряд ли он осилит переопределить стили бутстрапа

Comment: @andreymal извините, но полностью скинуть исходники я не могу. Но я гарантирую, что мои стили подключаются ПОЗЖЕ стилей бутстрапа, а стили, отвечающие за этот блок я кинул. Нигде выше не идет попыток переопределить стиль inputa.

Comment: @IvanBlohin а не надо скидывать исходники полностью, надо минимальный самодостаточный рабочий пример) А то, что на ideone, нерабочее и не самодостаточное, и делать выводы по нему трудно

Comment: @andreymal так подойдет? http://www.bootply.com/iutzRQ9GGE

Comment: @IvanBlohin да, теперь хорошо. Можно я это в вопрос красиво перенесу?

Comment: И здесь `#link-to-group-field { border-radius: 10px; }` всё-таки нормально работает

Comment: @andreymal да, конечно, как вам удобно. Спасибо, большое, но столько подводных камней, как в верстке, я еще не видел...